# Bootstrap template does not scroll on certain areas

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, scroll

So I have an application template that was built using bootstrap. Everything works fine except for when I view the website on a mobile phone. I am not able to scroll vertically from where the table starts on the the page. Clicking on the corners of the panels(the white area) in the right section I am able to scroll but any additional panels after that become unscrollable on a mobile. I have tested this with different phones and I get the same result. I thought it was because of the heavy use of javascripting files to make it work in IE8 and that was not the issue either. I'm guessing it has something to do with the tables as there are other pages without tables and they scroll just fine.

Here is the jsfiddle link: http://jsfiddle.net/amirshadaab/w6zppc65/2/

My tables lok something like this:

```
<div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-condensed">
            <tbody></tbody>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Job Title</td>
                    <td>Access</td>
                    <td>Main Office</td>
                    <td>Portal ID</td>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr class="clickableRow" data-url="edit_profile_admin_boot.html">
                    <td>Adams, Jeff</td>
                    <td>Appraiser</td>
                    <td>CCC ONE w/ limited portal access</td>
                    <td>Office 3</td>
                    <td>jadam1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickableRow" data-url="edit_profile_admin_boot.html">
                    <td>Adams, Kim</td>
                    <td>Appraiser</td>
                    <td>CCC ONE w/ limited portal access</td>
                    <td>Office 3</td>
                    <td>jadam1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickableRow" data-url="edit_profile_admin_boot.html">
                    <td>Adams, Mat</td>
                    <td>Appraiser</td>
                    <td>CCC ONE w/ limited portal access</td>
                    <td>Office 3</td>
                    <td>jadam1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickableRow" data-url="edit_profile_admin_boot.html">
                    <td>Briggins, Ada</td>
                    <td>Appraiser</td>
                    <td>CCC ONE w/ limited portal access</td>
                    <td>Office 3</td>
                    <td>jadam1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickableRow" data-url="edit_profile_admin_boot.html">
                    <td>Leonard, Adam</td>
                    <td>Appraiser</td>
                    <td>CCC ONE w/ limited portal access</td>
                    <td>Office 3</td>
                    <td>jadam1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickableRow" data-url="edit_profile_admin_boot.html">
                    <td>Leonard, Adam</td>
                    <td>Appraiser</td>
                    <td>CCC ONE w/ limited portal access</td>
                    <td>Office 3</td>
                    <td>jadam1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickableRow" data-url="edit_profile_admin_boot.html">
                    <td>Leonard, Adam</td>
                    <td>Appraiser</td>
                    <td>CCC ONE w/ limited portal access</td>
                    <td>Office 3</td>
                    <td>jadam1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickableRow" data-url="edit_profile_admin_boot.html">
                    <td>Leonard, Adam</td>
                    <td>Appraiser</td>
                    <td>CCC ONE w/ limited portal access</td>
                    <td>Office 3</td>
                    <td>jadam1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickableRow" data-url="edit_profile_admin_boot.html">
                    <td>Leonard, Adam</td>
                    <td>Appraiser</td>
                    <td>CCC ONE w/ limited portal access</td>
                    <td>Office 3</td>
                    <td>jadam1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr class="clickableRow" data-url="edit_profile_admin_boot.html">
                    <td>Leonard, Adam</td>
                    <td>Appraiser</td>
                    <td>CCC ONE w/ limited portal access</td>
                    <td>Office 3</td>
                    <td>jadam1</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Please do not use "bootstrap" tag, use "twitter-bootstrap" since it means something else

Comment: You can't get views because you used the wrong tag